# How to format my OS partition without any cd?

Tags: windows

I have a laptop running windows vista home and I don't have the installation DVD because it's came pre-installed , i want now to format the partition whish contains the OS but the windows does not let me because it's running from it . Is there a solution to do this? And i don't prefer to install third party softwares.

Maybe by doing a file contains command line that is executed to format the particion c: before windows starts

thanks

Comment: But if you install third-party software for this task, it will be gone when you format the disk!

Answer (score 3):

What is your goal? You just want to erase the entire PC before giving/selling/throwing it away? There are many tools that do this, one example is [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/), you just run it from a Floppy or a CD.

Answer (score 1):

BE EXTREMELY CAREFUL!  You will erase data.

Download and boot from a free [utility CD like GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).  It can create partitions, and I think even format NTFS partitions.